# Passing multiple parameters to SSRS with URL

Tags: url, reporting-services, parameter-passing, ssrs-2012

I'm using Visual Studio 16.4.5 with SSRS 15.0.1659.0

Currently, I'm trying to pass a URL in native mode with three parameters:

="https://reporting/ReportServer?/Production/Equipment/Prime%20On%20Rent%20No%20Shipper&AttachmentOption=N&Store=" & Fields!StoreNumber.Value & "&Division=" & Parameters!Division.Value

Every time I click the resulting box on the server side, I get:

```
An error has occurred during report processing. (rsProcessingAborted)
     Query execution failed for dataset 'DataSet1'. (rsErrorExecutingCommand)
          For more information about this error navigate to the report server on the local server machine, or enable remote errors
```

I've tried wrapping it in javascript, even though I don't want to use javascript for this. I just want to be able to open the target report with the parameters in it. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It looks like it should work. Have you tried using `Go To Report` to see if that gets an error? Check your CASE of the parameters.

Comment: I can't use [Go To Report] because they're not both in the same subfolder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, a couple of things:

1. I had the wrong alias for one of the tables in my query, so it couldn't be found.
2. I had to make the two initial variables accept multiple values so that I could join them in the final URL.

Once I fixed those issues, it worked!